# Laplace Transformation Applications

Tags: calculus, transformation, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

In one of our Mathematics lecture our Prof told us that similar to Logarithmic Transformations we can use Laplace Transformations to solve difficult equations.

What kind of equations do Laplace transformations help to solve ?

Comment: They are used to solve some differential equations because they transform the derivative and integral into multiplication and division by $s$ respectively.  The Laplace transform is used extensively in electrical engineering, particularly to understand, analyze and design control systems.

Comment: @iluvthee07: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Examples:_How_to_apply_the_properties_and_theorems

Answer (score 2):

Linear constant-coefficient ordinary and partial differential equations, mainly
(for the partial differential equation case, the coefficients are constant in the "time" variable, not necessarily the space variable).  Also some integral equations.

Answer (score 0):

Laplace Equations really shine when you start dealing with differential equations that have discontinuous or otherwise erratic behavior in them. 
Example:
Lets say you have a loaded spring set in motion (based off some IVP) on an elevator and you want to model how it moves as you go from floor 1 to 100, but the elevator stops intermittently at various floors (at which point there is no driving force) or it is rising or dropping to various stories until it reaches the 100th floor. I can think of it like I'm turning a functino on and off at various times t, and this is modelled using the heaviside function, which in order to solve ODE with heaviside functions in it you most likely will need to use Laplace transformations.

Another example:
I have a spring that can move up or down, and i "randomly" (you know when, but its not model-able by any single 'function') strike it with a hammer. It can be thought of like the hammer imparts a nearly infinite force for a infinitesimally small period, creating an infinite discontinuity, but the amount of energy that strike imparts is finite. This is modeled with the Dirac-delta (or impulse) function, which once again is a problem where Laplace works well for it.

Essentially since we are transforming our equations with an integral (Riemann sum) transform we can get away with dealing with non-differentiable points in our function without the equation exploding in our face.

Comment: There are classes of functions called convolutions, which you will come across heavily in many applications, that tend to see interesting things happen in laplace transforms. Convolutions are also actually a common output from Laplace Transforms. You probably can expect the laplace transform to be useful for almost any function that decays slower than exponential out at infinity, but some obviously have easier methods.

Comment: We observed in algebra that exponentials map multiplication to addition within the exponential space. Basically in linear differential equations we observe that a mapping exists between exponentials and differentiation to a similar vein, so the Laplace transform is a map for a differential operation to a space where it can be algebraically solved in a VERY similar way.